# What is the Visual Studio Performance Profiler "Force GC" button actually doing?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, profiler

I am trying to track down memory leaks in my application using the `Visual Studio Performance Profiler`

I use the profiler to:

1. carry out actions
2. Snapshot
3. Force GC
4. snapshot again

And I see all my object garbage collected correctly.

[image]

I do the same thing but using my application:

1. carry out actions
2. Snapshot
3. Force GC at runtime using the code:

   `GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   GC.Collect();`
4. snapshot again

But this time the objects are not collected and are still in memory.

So what is the difference between the `Force GC` button and the code `GC.Collect()` that I'm calling?

Comment: You can´t really force the collector to do anything, it´s entirely un-determistics. Having said this it´s merely per accident that using the profiler shows you anything different.

Comment: If you force a collection and your leak goes away, it never was a leak to begin with. Why did you arrive at the conclusion you have a leak? Also, if you allocate the objects in the same method as you put the `GC.Collect();` statement, if you're profiling a DEBUG build, or if the profiler application behaves like a debugger, it will prolong the lifetime of local variables, perhaps enough to make them be alive past the collection.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am just hunting for leaks at the moment on navigating to and from pages. I think you may be right though - the page may be closing itself and calling `GC.Collect` but because it's the page closing itself it may be holding onto everything at the time of the `GC.Collect`

Comment: If you placed the collection code inside a "page", whatever that is in your app, the page might be holding on to resources, yes. One common misconception I see when talking about .NET apps all the time is that people tend to feel that they use a lot of memory. However, that's just the garbage collector working as intended. There's no point in keeping memory to a minimum if you got loads of it. If, however, it never goes back down to some baseline, or the baseline keeps steadily growing, that's when you need to look for leaks.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain "You can´t really force the collector to do anything, it´s entirely un-determistics. " Actually, you can force it to do the collection as also mentioned in other comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Thanks to @Lass V. Karlsen for pointing me in the right direction with this comment: [What is the Visual Studio Performance Profiler "Force GC" button actually doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969852/what-is-the-visual-studio-performance-profiler-force-gc-button-actually-doing?noredirect=1#comment106056457_59969852)

It was completely obvious when I think about it.

My `Page` was disposing of itself and in the `Dispose` method I as calling:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

and of course because the page was still alive at that point it wasn't being garbage collected.

My solution was to do the following instead:

```
#if DEBUG
     Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         await Task.Delay(500);                   
         GC.Collect();
         GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
         GC.Collect();
     });
#endif
```

Notice I've wrapped it with a `DEBUG` compiler directive as I don't think this is the advised way of doing it, but for the purpose of hunting memory leaks it works well